# How do I make this display in my textbox?

Tags: c#, linq, user-interface, search

I am trying to make the result display in my text box. For a regular windows console the code would work, but how do I do it with a GUI?

The whole `Console.WriteLine` part of the code has a red underline.

```
var listOfWords = Regex.Matches(File.ReadAllText(textBoxInputFile.Text), @"\w+")
                       .Cast<Match>()
                       .Select((m, pos) => new { Word = m.Value, Pos = pos })
                       .GroupBy(s => s.Word, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                       .Select(g => new { Word = g.Key, PosInText = g.Select(z => z.Pos).ToList() })
                       .ToList();


var result = listOfWords.GroupBy(x => x)
                         .Select(x => new { Key = x.Key, Count = x.Count() })
                         .OrderBy(x => x.Key);

result.ToList().ForEach(x =>
{
    textBoxShowText.Text = Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", x.Key, x.Count);
});
```

Comment: Have you tried searching for what the "red underline" is saying?..

Comment: How you are suppose to display the records? Multiple records in one textbox?

Answer (score 1):

`Console.Writeline` method is intended to write something to the console, as it is stated in its name.

You're trying to set the text of textbox, so you just need to assign string value to the `Text` property.

If you need to format this value, you need to use `String.Format` method.

Also note - you're trying to use it in a loop, so it looks like you need to append `Text` property instead of replacing it on each iteration.

So it should be something like:

```
textBoxShowText.Text += String.Format("{0}:{1}", x.Key, x.Count);
```

Comment: I keep getting "At least one object must implement IComparabe"

Comment: @Bake hmm... you haven't mentioned this in original question. and it isn't related to any usage of `Console.WriteLine` and so on. What exactly line throws this exception?

Comment: Your part of the code should work. I think I miss something in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `Console.WriteLine` by `String.Format`

Answer (score 0):

every value append with "" then it will convert to string value 
so you can write

> textBoxShowText.Text = x.Key+":"+x.Count ;

Using this code the result will display the last record only so 
you can use Listview control in you are using windows form application to show these records.
or 
use textarea if you are working on web application.